# Cant get inner loops to add up properly

Tags: python, loops, nested

My issue is with my user input totals for rainfall not adding up properly

my assumption is that it is not adding the 1st month in when asked on multiple years as

[image: problem explained]

```
def main():

    #define accumulators
    monthRain = 0
    year = 0
    monthTotal = 0
    months = 0
    total = 0 

    #get # of years
    year = int(input("Enter the number of years to collect data for: "))

    #define month total befor it is changed below with year + 1
    monthTotal = year * 12

    #define how many months per year
    months = 12

    #Find average rainfall per month
    for year in range(year):
        #accumulator for rain per month
        total = 0
        #get rainfall per month
        print('\nNext you will enter 12 months of rainfall data for year', year + 1)
        for month in range(months):
            print("Enter the rainfall for month", month + 1, end=" ")
            monthRain = float(input(': '))

            #add monthly raingfall to accumulator
            total += monthRain
            average = total / monthTotal

    #total months of data 
    print('\nYou have entered data for', monthTotal,'months')

    #total rainfall
    print('\nThe total rainfall for the collected months is:', total)
    print('The average monthly rainfall for the collected months is:', format(average, '.2f' ))

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `total = 0` out of the for loop. Every time you enter the loop, it sets `total` to zero. Take it out and put it before the for loop. I think that will fix it.

Let me know...

Comment: No problem. happy programming

Comment: This was really racking my brain........it feels so nice knowing that it was a tiny error that caused this and everything works perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

At the start of every year entry, you zero `total`, then print `total` at the end. The 64 you see is actually the 2nd year's rainfall, and the 1st year is being thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be resetting the `total` for each year. That's why you were missing a year's worth of data. The total rainfall in the example you provided was `131` and the average is approximately `5.46`. I ran your example and got the following.

```
Enter the number of years to collect data for: 2
('\nNext you will enter 12 months of rainfall data for year', 1)
Enter the rainfall for month 1  
: 3
Enter the rainfall for month 2  
: 4
Enter the rainfall for month 3  
: 6
Enter the rainfall for month 4  
: 7
Enter the rainfall for month 5  
: 9
Enter the rainfall for month 6  
: 8
Enter the rainfall for month 7  
: 5
Enter the rainfall for month 8  
: 3
Enter the rainfall for month 9  
: 4
Enter the rainfall for month 10  
: 1
Enter the rainfall for month 11  
: 8
Enter the rainfall for month 12  
: 9
('\nNext you will enter 12 months of rainfall data for year', 2)
Enter the rainfall for month 1  
: 3
Enter the rainfall for month 2  
: 6
Enter the rainfall for month 3  
: 7
Enter the rainfall for month 4  
: 3
Enter the rainfall for month 5  
: 4
Enter the rainfall for month 6  
: 1
Enter the rainfall for month 7  
: 9
Enter the rainfall for month 8  
: 7
Enter the rainfall for month 9  
: 8
Enter the rainfall for month 10  
: 4
Enter the rainfall for month 11  
: 5
Enter the rainfall for month 12  
: 7
('\nYou have entered data for', 24, 'months')
('\nThe total rainfall for the collected months is:', 131.0)
('The average monthly rainfall for the collected months is:', '5.46')
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
#define accumulators
monthRain = 0
year = 0
monthTotal = 0
months = 0
total = 0 

#get # of years
year = int(input("Enter the number of years to collect data for: "))

#define month total befor it is changed below with year + 1
monthTotal = year * 12

#define how many months per year
months = 12

#Find average rainfall per month
for year in range(year):
    #accumulator for rain per month
    #get rainfall per month
    print('\nNext you will enter 12 months of rainfall data for year', year + 1)
    for month in range(months):
        print ("Enter the rainfall for month", month + 1, " ")
        monthRain = float(input(': '))

        #add monthly raingfall to accumulator
        total += monthRain
        average = total / monthTotal

#total months of data 
print('\nYou have entered data for', monthTotal,'months')

#total rainfall
print('\nThe total rainfall for the collected months is:', total)
print('The average monthly rainfall for the collected months is:', format(average, '.2f' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The 64 is actually the result of your second year.

Because you have `total = 0` inside your loop, it is **rest** after every year. Thus the values of the first year are overwritten by the values of the second year.

Take `total=0` outside of the loop. That should fix the problem.

Other than that I wonder, why you have a variable for month, if you're using a constant 12 to calculate `monthTotal`.